# Automatically connect Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client

Tags: windows, cisco-vpn

Every time I log onto my PC I have to also manually connect to a VPN network to access servers based at another office. Is there anyway to automate this on startup? I have checked the 'Connect on start-up' option but it has no effect. I still have to load the client myself, input my password and accept a certificate each time.

We use Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client version 2.4.0202.

Answer (score 2):

At least in our environment, even though the option exists in the client the feature can be disabled on the VPN server side.  In some cases, this is done for security to prevent passwords being saved or a myriad of other reasons.

Certain GPO configurations can also prevent proper auto/re connect.